Clicking Button on Selenium/Python
I'm currently trying to build out an automation that requires selecting on a button from a pop up screen but I've been unsuccessful. There are two buttons and the one I'm wanting to select is the "Save" portion. Here is currently how the code looks like for the button:
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary"><span>Cancel</span></button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-strong"><span>Save</span></button>

I have successfully coded a portion of my automation to click on buttons but for some reason it isn't working on this pop up screen button.
So far, I've tried the following code without success as it simply crashes my program:
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[@class='btn btn-strong')]").click()

WebDriverWait(driver,10000).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[contains(@class,'btn btn-strong')]"))
).click()

Here is the xpath code I was able to copy
//*[@id="main-content-body"]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/section/div[2]/div[2]/button[2]

I tried writing out a query but I keep getting an error
input_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id="main-content-body"]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/section/div[2]/div[2]/button[2]))


is the pop up an element inside the webpage or a separate browser window?

Hey @soundwave! It is an element inside the webpage. I was actually able to copy the xcode from the inspect tool. Here it is: //*[@id="main-content-body"]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/section/div[2]/div[2]/button[2]

Whether it is due to the presence of an iframe in the popup window, when using selenium, it usually occurs that the element cannot be manipulated because of the presence of an iframe.
Or you can try positioning the button using the text attribute of the span element, which is also generally clickable.
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[@class='btn btn-strong')]/span[text()='Save']").click()

